# Mudança de valor de variavel no react-native

Tags: react-native

sou novo no react-native então acredito que isso e uma dúvida bem básica. Como passo o valor de uma variável[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] para meu template JSX? Quero que quando eu chamar a função SomaG1 ele atribui um valor para ContG1 e esse valor se altere no componente do JSX.

Comment: Poderia, por favor, colocar o seu código para facilitar auxiliar na resposta?

Comment: Filipe é o que esta na img em cima, não esta aparecendo ?

Comment: Geralmente isso fazemos com state: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/state

Comment: @LucasdeCarvalho obrigado cara, mais acho que ainda não entendi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É necessário criar um elemento no [state no seu componente](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/state). Segue exemplo:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button, Text, View } from "react-native";


class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        contG1: 0
    };
  }

  somaG1() {
    this.setState({contG1:this.state.contG1+1})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Valor contG1: {this.state.contG1}</Text>
        <Button onPress={() => this.somaG1()} title="Clique para somar" />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Você também pode ver [funcionando online](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-native-dxlp1).

O `state` tem o papel de controlar o estado daquele componente, nesse caso o componente App da sua aplicação. É importante lembrar que ele é imutável, sendo alterado com a função `setState`.

Para maiores informações sobre o state, você pode acessar a [documentação](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html).

Comment: Cara ainda não consegui, pq ele fica dando um errinho

Comment: Diz que a funcao constructor não existe.

Comment: @FabricioCarneiro perceba que eu mudei a forma como estou criando o componente. Você estava fazendo um componente sem estado (stateless component), como precisamos de um componente que tenha estado, precisamos de um class component. Para mais informações, você pode ler esse [post](https://blog.rocketseat.com.br/react-do-zero-ciclo-de-vida-stateless-components-e-arquitetura-flux/)

Comment: Acho que entendi mano, valeu em cara!